# Calculating HashCode function in HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hashcode, mapr

I want to move some files from one location to another location [both the locations are on HDFS] and need to verify that the data has moved correctly.

In order to compare the data moved, I was thinking of calculating hash code on both the files and then comparing if they are equal. If equal, I would term the data movement as correct else the data movement has not happened correctly.

But I have a couple of questions regarding this.

1. Do I need to use the hashCode technique at all in first place? I am using MapR distribution and I read somewhere that data movement when done, implement hashing of the data at the backend and make sure that it has been transferred correctly. So is it guaranteed that when data will be moved inside HDFS, it will be consistent and no anomaly will be inserted while movement?
2. Is there any other way that I can use in order to make sure that the data moved is consistent across locations?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You are asking about data copying. Just use [DistCp](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/distcp.html).

> **DistCp** (distributed copy) is a tool used for large inter/intra-cluster copying. It uses MapReduce to effect its *distribution, error handling and recovery, and reporting*.

```
#sample example 
$hadoop distcp hdfs://nn1:8020/foo/bar \ 
                hdfs://nn2:8020/bar/foo
```

This will expand the namespace under /foo/bar on nn1 into a temporary file, partition its contents among a set of map tasks, and start a copy on each TaskTracker from nn1 to nn2.

---

**EDIT**

`DistCp` uses `MapReduce` to effect its *distribution, error handling and recovery, and reporting*.

After a copy, it is recommended that `one generates and cross-checks` a listing of the source and destination to ·verify that the copy was truly successful·. Since DistCp employs both MapReduce and the FileSystem API, *issues in or between any of the three could adversely and silently affect the copy.*

---

**EDIT**

The common method I used to check the `source` and `dist` files was *check the number of files and the specified size of each file.* This can be done by generate a `manifest` at the source, then check at the `dist` both the number and size.

Comment: The question is not regarding what to use? I can use DistCp to copy my data across. Rather I need to validate if the data has been copied successfully without any error. Appreciate your answer but that will be great if you can answer the #1 in my original question! Will using DistCp gurantees an error free copy?

Comment: Thanks a bunch Luoluo! One  question. You mentioned that you recommend to generate and cross check a listing of both source ad destination! That was the #2 in the original question. Is there an efficient way then using the counts or hashCode for source and destination?

Comment: Thanks LuoLuo! +1 for your effort :) I will try implementing your suggestion and will definitely accept it as an answer once done. Thanks once again!

Answer (score 0):

In HDFS, move doesn't physically move the data (blocks) across the data nodes. It actually changes the name space in HDFS metadata. Where as copying data from one HDFS location to another HDFS location, we have two ways;

1. copy
2. parallel copy distcp

In General copy, it doesn't check the integrity of blocks. If you want data integrity while copying file from one location to another location in same HDFS cluster use CheckSum concept by modifying the FsShell.java class or write your own class using HDFS Java API.

In Case of distCp, HDFS checks the data integrity while copying data from One HDFS cluster to another HDFS Cluster.

Comment: Naga - Luoluo has some suggestions for me to check the validity of my data move. Any that you are implementing?